# Dev App Server does not support App Engine Flexible Environment applications

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-boot

I'm trying to deploy spring boot app to app engine and receiving this error:

```
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Dev App Server does not support App Engine Flexible Environment applications.
```

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you have put appengine-web.xml file under src/main/webapp/WEB-INF folder.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, but I found that the problem was related to the way the app was packed. 
It seems that it is required to be a **WAR**.

For example, you can put the following line in the **pom.xml** of your app:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

But first, make sure you check what @Ajitesh said about the **appengine-web.xml** file.

For more details, follow these links: [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/issues/191) and [possible solution](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/pull/231).

Answer (score 1):

The message is accurate: App Engine Flexible environment doesn't have a local emulator like Dev App Server currently.

Comment: Rodrigo, I am checking the RunMojo.java:352 and it looks for a /WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml in the project and if not found, we get this error. Apparently, my project is GAE standard configured, I am just using a parent Maven project and the plugin is included there. Shall we move the plugin declaration into pom.xml-s of each child web modules to have it go? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a file under directory "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml" with the content as below

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
     <version>1</version>
     <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
     <runtime>java8</runtime>
</appengine-web-app>
```